# Toggle CSS class on image with Supersized API/Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, supersized

I'm using the Supersized jQuery plugin to animate my background, and I've used their API to have the slides change when an image/link is clicked (I used:

```
$('.navone').click(function(){
api.goTo(1);
});
```

Now I need the active image/link to have a background image when it's slide is active, so far I have this:

```
jQuery(function($){
if(vars.current_slide = 1){
$('.navone').toggleClass('active');
});
});
```

This doesn't appear to do anything, I'm still fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery, any advice would be great.

EDIT:

I’ve put

```
if (vars.current_slide == 1){
(‘#navone’).addClass(‘.active’);
} else {
(‘#navone’).removeClass(‘.active’);
}
```

In the `afterAnimation : function(){` section of supersized.shutter.js but it doesn’t seem to be doing anything at all. Any advice?

Comment: What's your `jQuery` version ?

Comment: Try using `==` instead of just `=` here: `(vars.current_slide = 1)`

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the statement to a "switch" statement and added the class to initially start on the actual link.

```
afterAnimation : function(){
        $('#navone,#navtwo,#navthree,#navfour,#navfive,#navsix,#navseven').removeClass('active');
        switch(vars.current_slide) {
            case 0 : $('#navone').addClass('active'); break;
            case 1 : $('#navtwo').addClass('active'); break;
            case 2 : $('#navthree').addClass('active'); break;
            case 3 : $('#navfour').addClass('active'); break;
            case 4 : $('#navfive').addClass('active'); break;
            case 5 : $('#navsix').addClass('active'); break;
            case 6 : $('#navseven').addClass('active'); break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //waits until the document is ready
    $('.navone').click(function(){ //bind a function to the element with class navone
        $('.active').removeClass('active'); //remove all active class
        $(this).addClass('active'); //add class active to the navone link
        api.goTo(1); //make the supersized go to the the slide 1
    });
});
```

I not 100% sure about the .goto function from this api, but if it works on the first line it will work now. :)

supersized seems to create an automatic navigation, but you don't have to apoint it in the function, try using this, and checks if it works, then you can restylize the divs:

```
<div id="controls-wrapper" class="load-item">
    <div id="controls">
        <ul id="slide-list"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It keeps the class active, but I need the class to toggle, so that when the slideshow moves on, it changes the next image/link to 'active'

Comment: hmm, it seems that supersized creates an automatic navigation, I'm going to edit my answear, just a minute!

Comment: Had spent a while fiddling with Supersized's navigation trying to use my own images and positioning, didn't really get anywhere with it.